# finding a point in a cylinder

Tags: coordinate-systems

I am trying to build a basic color approximation model for a website. I think the HSL would be the most efficient model to use.  I remember from school the formulae for a cylinder is 
        $$\pi r^2 h$$

height = L, S = radius and I am given an angle for H. Given an HSL value, how do I convert it to X, Y, Z coordinates?

Comment: $\pi r^2h$ is the formula for the *volume* of a cylinder and has nothing to do with the calculation you're after.

Comment: do you know what i need then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the height $L$ is the height above the $xy$-plane, $z$ obviously equals $L$.

By basic trigonometry, a point in the $xy$-plane a distance $r$ from the origin and at an angle of $\theta$ from the $x$-axis is located at $(r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta)$, and this formula is preserved when the plane is translated upward/downward.

Thus (using $H$ to represent the angle itself):

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
x & = & S\cos H \\
y & = & S\sin H \\
z & = & L
\end{eqnarray*}$$

Comment: awesome, thanks